# How to use sscan in Redis with Lua script?

Tags: lua, redis

I want to get number of values when `SSCAN command` is finished.

```
127.0.0.1:6379[2]> sadd Test:Info:Site 'www.naver.com' 'www.google.com' 'www.daum.net' 'www.korea.com'
(integer) 4
127.0.0.1:6379[2]> smembers Test:Info:Site
    1) "www.naver.com"
    2) "www.daum.net"
    3) "www.korea.com"
    4) "www.google.com"
```

I want to return "0"

```
127.0.0.1:6379[2]> sscan Test:Info:Site 0 match '*niver*'
    1) "0"
    2) (empty list or set)    <--- count this
```

I want to return "1"

```
127.0.0.1:6379[2]> sscan Test:Info:Site 0 match '*naver*'
    1) "0"
    2) 1) "www.naver.com"    <--- count this
```

I want to return "3"

```
127.0.0.1:6379[2]> sscan Test:Info:Site 0 match '*com*'
    1) "0"
    2) 1) "www.naver.com"     <-- count
       2) "www.korea.com"     <-- count
       3) "www.google.com"    <-- count
```

I can't access value of search result.

```
127.0.0.1:6379[2]> EVAL "return #redis.call('sscan',KEYS[1],0,'match',ARGV[1])" 1 'Test:Info:Site' '*com*'
(integer) 2
    127.0.0.1:6379[2]> EVAL "return #redis.call('sscan',KEYS[1],0,'match',ARGV[1])" 1 'Test:Info:Site' '*niver*'
(integer) 2
```

Comment: Sidenote: Using the `SCAN` family from Lua, might well be an anti-pattern. `SCAN` was added to redis to be able to stay in the O(n) domain with a determinable (n) when needing to get all keys (or members) eventually. When doing this from Lua, you are blocking other clients. Technically possible, like @itamarhaber shows, but tread with care.

Comment: @TwBert I agree with the logic of your argument, but `SCAN` commands are actually better then their counterparts in terms of memory consumption even in Lua. That said, everything is blocking but long-running operations even more so :)

Comment: Agreed, for certain scenarios it is good. But I wouldn't use it on high cardinality keys, it simply doesn't scale within a server side blocking script. For those scenarios, you need a client to do the repeated calls.

Comment: I totally concur, admittedly I could have been stricter with my answer and caution against it :)

Comment: @ItamarHaber unrelated: seen [this?](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBranePackage/issues/62#issuecomment-357463264)

Answer (score 4):

It appears like you're trying to perform [`SSCAN`](https://redis.io/commands/sscan) from a Lua script in order to do pattern matching against the Set's members and return the count. If that is the case, you need to repeat the the call to `SSCAN` until the cursor returns to '0', and count each iteration's results.

Here's an example of how it should be done:

```
$ cat sscan.lua
local key, pat = KEYS[1], ARGV[1]
local cursor, res = 0, 0

repeat
  local rep = redis.call('SSCAN', key, cursor, 'MATCH', pat)
  cursor = rep[1]
  res = res + #rep[2]
until cursor == '0'

return res

$ redis-cli --eval sscan.lua Test:Info:Site , "*niver*"
(integer) 0
$ redis-cli --eval sscan.lua Test:Info:Site , "*naver*"
(integer) 1
$ redis-cli --eval sscan.lua Test:Info:Site , "*com*"
(integer) 3
```